# Fetch value from the table by comparing comma sperated string column value using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I need one help. I need to fetch value from table comparing the comma separated string value which is present inside the column. I am explaining my table below.

> db_details

```
id       comment       day_id     basic_id

 1         Hello         1          1

 2         Razz          1           2

 3        Good           2          1
```

> db_basic:

```
id      special_id      name

 1       1,2             Ram

 2        2              Rahul

 3       1,3             Rocky
```

Here I need to fetch value by joining two table. I have only data like this `comment=Good and day_id= 2 and special_id=2` . As here I have the `special_id` are in comma separated string , I need to fetch all value from both table by using the given data means the `special_id` should be match with comma separated string. I need sql query for this.

Comment: You can use LIKE OR FIND_IN_SET query.BTW it's not a good approach to have comma seperated id's .try to add them as new row every-time. This is called normalization

Comment: Post you query ..

Comment: You can use 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('2', special_id);

Answer (score 0):

=> Mysql compare comma-separated field use `"FIND_IN_SET();"`.

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('2', special_id);
```